# on.click is firing after second click

Tags: jquery

```
<div>
  <span>click me</span> <!-- this is coming from ajax request -->
</div>

function show_me(selector) {
  selector.on('click', function(){
    alert('showing')
  })
}

$('div').on('click', 'span', function(){
  show_me($(this))
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6paqvfos/

`show_me()` will be used elsewhere and it has to require the selector with it with the click event.

I want to click on the span only once to show the alert.

I'm using delegation here `$('div').on('click', 'span', function(){` because the span will come in ajax so I have to be sure it exist.

Comment: Can explain what you are trying to *achieve* please?  As it appears you just need to change `show_me` to `function show_me() { alert("showing");}` which matches your *"how can I use show_me while clicking only once"*.

Comment: Ok, so `function show_me(selector) { $(this).hide(); }` - your emphasis is on calling `show_me` with a selector, which you already do.  The emphasis should be on what it does and why you're adding additional click events.

Comment: On second viewing... you complain that "on.click is firing after second click" - not "*only* after second click" - do you mean "*on.click is **stil** firing on second click*"?  The problem is you have **two** on.clicks - which do you mean?

Comment: You need to *remove* the `selector.on("click"` part - that's then *waiting* for *another* click (which you appear not to want).   Given the limited example of what happens in show_me, it's hard to see why you would want this.  It looks like you want to call show_me from numerous sources, one of which might be a click and to know in the method if it was a click - is that right?

Comment: Your fiddle and example only show what you don't want to happen - which is easily fixed as presented (remove the second .on(click)).  What *do* you want to happen?

Comment: Something like this?  https://jsfiddle.net/9r5a27xv/  if this isn't want you mean, you'll need to add a lot more explanation :)

Comment: This fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/9r5a27xv/1/) matches your question as the question is worded and considering your comments.   Is that what you're after?  Trying to help you determine your solution.

Comment: well, I thought I did say I needed to use the `show_me()` func as it is meaning with selector and click event. Post updated, I'll remove my previous comments here.

Comment: *as it is* is with a second click event handler that won't get fired until the user does a second click, which is the problem described in your title.  So you've said "I have a problem but I can't change *any* of the code, please help me".   What does that even mean?

Comment: Maybe you need to change how/when you call `show_me` and not all it on a button click (eg call it on document.ready) but then what context are you expecting for `this`?

Comment: I guess I have to remove the click event from `show_me()` then, thanks for your help, I just thought there's a simpler workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the event trigger again when the click happens.
Use unbind the click event first:
`

```
<div>
  <span>click me</span> <!-- this is coming from ajax request -->
</div>

function show_me(selector) {
  selector.unbind('click').on('click', function(){
    alert('showing')
  })
}

$('div').on('click', 'span', function(){
  show_me($(this))
})
```

`

Comment: Unfortunately the first click `$('div').on('click', 'span'...` is not unbound this way.

Comment: Please also note the `ubind` was deprecated over 8 years ago, along with (`.bind()`) - I think you mean `.off()`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `.click` like this

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  //your return
}
```